# Changes in R-squared

Tags: variance, residuals, r-squared, intuition

I was reading online, and I found that

If the Variance of X increases then the value of R-squared increases

If the Variance of the residuals increases then the value of R-squared decreases

Can someone explain the intuition behind these two statements.

I am generally confused about the impact of variance of X or the residuals on the explanatory power of the regression.

Comment: Especially if it's online, you should link to your source for context.

Comment: It's a general question on the impact of new regressors on R-squared. The website didn't give an example.

Comment: The relationship between $R^2$  and the spread of the independent variables ($X$) is discussed and illustrated at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314.  The relationship with the residuals is obvious once you recognize that $1-R^2$ is directly related to the variance of the residuals.

Answer (score 4):

It's best to think in terms of ratios, how much error is explained by $x$, how much is residual.

If we think of a super-simple regression with one independent variable and slope = 1, just $y = x + \epsilon$, then $\mathrm{Var}(Y) =\mathrm{Var}(X) + \mathrm{Var}(\epsilon)$. (Of course, using the assumption that the residual error $\epsilon$ is uncorrelated with $X$.) From that, it's straightforward that as the variance of $X$ increases, so does the variance of $Y$--if you observe a wider range of $X$ values, you'll also observe a wider range of $Y$ values.

However, we assume that the residual error is fixed, it doesn't change with $X$. And we know that R^2 is defined as the ratio of "explained variance" to "total variance". So

$$
R^2 = \frac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{\mathrm{Var}(Y)} = \frac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{\mathrm{Var}(X) + \mathrm{Var}(\epsilon)}
$$

And it's pretty clear that, given a fixed value of $\mathrm{Var}(\epsilon)$ as $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ increases the $R^2$ approaches 1.

This extends easily if the slope isn't equal to 1--the important assumption is that $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(\epsilon)$ are uncorrelated.

I find simulation a nice way to understand things too, you can see the effect with the following R code which simulates data for various values of $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Var}(\epsilon)$, fits models, extracts the R squared values, and plots the results in a heatmap.

```
rsqd <- function(varx = 10, varresid = 3, n = 30, betax = 2) {
    x <- rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(varx))
    y <- betax * x + rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(varresid))
    return(summary(lm(y ~ x))$r.squared)
}

vx <- 1:20
vr <- 1:20

results <- expand.grid(vx = vx, vr = vr)
results$rsq <- numeric(nrow(results))

for (i in 1:nrow(results)) {
    results$rsq[i] <- rsqd(varx = results$vx[i], varresid = results$vr[i])
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(results, aes(x = vx, y = vr, fill = rsq)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

Despite the model always being "right", if the variation in `x` is small but the residual error is large, the R-squared is quite low (upper left corner). The situation is reversed in the lower right, where the residual error is small compared to the variation of `x`, and thus compared to the variation explained by `x`.